# How to execute 32-bit shellcode on a 64-bit Linux system?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, x86-64, 32-bit, shellcode

I am learning to construct my own shellcodes following examples from the [*Gray Hat Hacking*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071077316) textbook. They have given examples to execute shellcodes on 32-bit Linux systems but when I assembled them in my system with the appropriate flags (maybe I could be wrong on this part) I am not getting the expected results.

The name of my shellcode executable is `sc2`.

```
section .text
global _start

_start:
xor eax, eax
mov al, 0x46
xor ebx, ebx
xor ecx, ecx
int 0x80

xor eax, eax
push eax
push 0x68732f2f
push 0x6e692f2f
mov ebx, esp
push eax
push ebx
mov ecx, esp
xor edx, edx
mov al, 0xb
int 0x80
```

```
# nasm -f elf sc2.asm -o sc2.o
# ld -m elf_i386 sc2.o -o sc2
# ./sc2
segmentation fault
# objdump -M intel -d ./sc2
./sc2:     file format elf32-i386
Disassembly of section .text:
08049000 <_start>:
 8049000:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
 8049002:   b0 46                   mov    al,0x46
 8049004:   31 db                   xor    ebx,ebx
 8049006:   31 c9                   xor    ecx,ecx
 8049008:   cd 80                   int    0x80
 804900a:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
 804900c:   50                      push   eax
 804900d:   68 2f 2f 73 68          push   0x68732f2f
 8049012:   68 2f 2f 69 6e          push   0x6e692f2f
 8049017:   89 e3                   mov    ebx,esp
 8049019:   50                      push   eax
 804901a:   53                      push   ebx
 804901b:   89 e1                   mov    ecx,esp
 804901d:   31 d2                   xor    edx,edx
 804901f:   b0 0b                   mov    al,0xb
 8049021:   cd 80                   int    0x80
# gdb -q ./sc2
Reading symbols from ./sc2...
(No debugging symbols found in ./sc2)
(gdb) r
Starting program: sc2 
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08049023 in ?? ()
```

From what I can gather, I believe the code got executed, but gives a segfault without giving a shell. What am I missing?

(My system details: Mine is a 64-bit Kali Linux)

Comment: use `strace ./sc2` to review the system call trace information for debug purposes.It should give you hints as to what might be wrong with your int 0x80 calls.

Comment: Don't use numeric immediates if you don't have to.  NASM lets you use `push '//bi'` for example, which would have made the typo bug obvious.

Comment: Thanks Michael and Peter. I've learned something new. I'll remember your tips. Thank you guys and thanks John for the helpful edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your push immediate instructions, and the command you are actually trying to execute is `//in//sh`.  As no such file exists, the `execve` system call fails, which means that it returns.  So your program continues executing past the last `int 0x80`, after which there is only garbage that crashes your program when executed as instructions.

Comment: Thanks Nate. What you said is right. I know the mistake is silly. But thanks for going through the code and pointing out the error!! It worked and I got the shell!!